# What's it called when you've got little crumbs sticking to your foot

Tags: word-usage

If crumbs stick to someone's feet while walking through am unswept kitchen,what will be used if they end up in the bed bothering that person?

"I hate the feeling of crumbs under my feet." But what is this feeling known as? And what is it called when they stick to our feet in the bed?

So how will native express this idea?

> The crumbs **prick** my feet.

P.S. Context edited

Comment: It's what I would call [a slovenly bed](https://books.google.it/books?id=N86XDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT142&lpg=PT142&dq=slovenly+bed&source=bl&ots=Z8WSVL-cUV&sig=ACfU3U2dG78SxLPRRnqlQYEyiH-3IEPIsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij0aeJkbbhAhWlxoUKHdUxA8sQ6AEwEXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=slovenly%20bed&f=false) with or without food debris.

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific word for this exact meaning. But "prick" would work for the general sensation of a small hard thing being pressed into your skin.

If the crumbs are in bed then they are more likely to *itch*, or *scratch* your back rather than prick your feet.

Comment: Casual use of the word 'prick' can be misunderstood.

Comment: Sandy, dusty, powdery or granulated matter can _irritate_ the skin.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it for a while, **[eating in bed](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1301&bih=613&tbm=bks&ei=M9mlXOO8JMv3kwXhzaHQCA&q=crumbs%20%22eating%20in%20bed%22&oq=crumbs%20%22eating%20in%20bed%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4801.7856.0.8715.8.8.0.0.0.0.152.692.7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.shy65mzTj7g)** and finding **[bed crumbs](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bed%20Crumbs)** is a bit like [**getting sand between your toes**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/get-sand-between-your-toes.3258346/) after a day out on the beach. Both pretty normal consequences but nonetheless very annoying.

With that context being clear, I would say the following

> - My feet feel ***sticky*** in bed
>     There are ***sticky*** bed crumbs
>     I've got bed crumbs **clinging** to my feet
>     I've got crumbs **stuck** between my toes

[image]

> Sticky feet/sand